# Downloading a custom plugin from the Moodle server

Tags: server, moodle, moodle-api

I am currently using a Moodle on a private server to test plug-ins which will then be put onto the main Moodle for public access. There is a plug-in on the private Moodle which I would like to put onto the main Moodle server. I have administrative access to the Moodle on the private server but not access to the actually server directory itself. I was wondering is there a way to download the plug-in directly from Moodle rather than from the server directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did some changes on this plugin on your private server and you want to move them to prod server? (If not installing from Moodle plugin directory should be possible.)

If yes, I think you would need to zip your plugin from private server, that shouldn't be an issue as you mention you have access to file system there, and deploy it to prod via zip functionality.

If it seems that you cannot install that plugin from directory or zip, it means likely that your web server of your prod Moodle doesn't have write access to plugin folder, in that case there is no other way how to install plugin via UI.

See https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Installing_plugins#Installing_directly_from_the_Moodle_plugins_directory for more information